# SQL Server single user mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, connection

Im experiencing an issue with a production server. I can connect to the server from only one program at a time. Eg, when I connect from SQL Management Studio then nobody else can, and vice versa with a different user. It's like the server is in single user mode, except, it's in multi user mode.

Any ideas?

I get this error message when connecting:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to myserver\ myserver.
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing 
a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured 
to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, 
error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) 
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things I can think of

**SQL Server in Single User Mode**

SQL Server Service has parameters that can be used to start it in SINGLE USER mode. Start\RUN `Services.msc`, go to the SQL Server Service and double check to ensure that a `-m` parameter is not set.

**Database in Single User Mode**

Your DATABASE may be set to SINGLE USER mode.

Try this command

`ALTER DATABASE [DBNAME] SET MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT`

**Application in Single User Mode**

If you use a `-m` parameter with SQLCMD or Management Studio, then you can limit the number of connections that go to SQL Server. Check your shortcuts for this. However, I think it is unlikely that you have set every single application with a `-m`.

**Edit / Suggestion:** There are a lot of adminstrators on ServerFault.com that may be able to assist you even more.